# array index replace with another array same index in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want only first array non empty index with second array with same index, meaning just in this case replace first array index 0 with second array index 0:

```
$all_images => array:2 [ 0 => "00fb319e3af47a5600d39248ad5ea9c2.png"

                         1 => null ]

$images => array:2 [ 0 => "1508159073atouch-q12-tablet-new-white-color-27-09-2017.png"

                     1 => "1508159073atouch-q12-tablet-new-white-color-30-07-2017.png" ]
```

The result:

```
$New_images => array:2 [ 0 => "00fb319e3af47a5600d39248ad5ea9c2.png"

                         1 => "1508159073atouch-q12-tablet-new-white-color-30-07-2017.png" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out the empty values and add (union of the two arrays):

```
$New_images = array_filter($all_images) + $images;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for array merge.

```
$a = [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'];
$b = [1 => 'z'];

var_dump($b+$a);
```

After re-reading, I misunderstood the question. You can fill in null values with a loop.

```
foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
    if (! $v ) {
        $a[$k] = $b[$k];
    }
}

var_dump($a);
```